# Bootstrap 5 only working partially - Color, margin and padding classes missing

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I trying to get BS5 up and running with a simple sass setup. I am following the guidelines and importing the sass partials in the correct order but no margin, padding, color classes are generated for some reason. So when i try to use "bg-primary" or "p-3" they simply don't work. The neccesary classes are not in the compiles stylesheet.

Styling of forms is working as intended and grids but what am i missing to make everything work?

If i include the cdn version of BS5 in my markup everything works perfectly. I am using version 5.1.3

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/modal";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/forms";
```

Comment: You're probably missing `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` which is the main one.

Comment: Further test reveals that when i remove the last include "forms" everything works.
Seems very strange

Comment: Well, great then! :P

Comment: @SiddharthBhansali No thats if you just want to load the entire framework

Comment: Yes, I checked and the **margin** and **padding** are in the `utilities` file. So try and include that and see? https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/main/scss/_utilities.scss

Comment: Seems the problem is elsewehere. When i compile using command line standalone sass it works. I am compiling this through Parcel js (v2) so i created a github issue.

Comment: I'm getting the same missing pieces in Bootstrap Sass. `utilities` does not include the margin and padding; it's only a short 56 lines long without any spacing declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a bug in Parcel js v2 somehow. Compiling this from command line with the sass module only works perfectly. I created an issue on this on Parcels github.